# how to query unique label value by promsql

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a metrics like this:

```
hello_info(a="1",b="t1") 0
hello_info(a="1",b="t2") 0
hello_info(a="1",b="t3") 1 
hello_info(a="2",b="t4") 2
```

and I want to get all unique label values
Kind of like

```
select distinct (a) from (hello_info) where value == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot select label values, but you can select a list of timelines each having a unique label:

```
sum by (a) (hello_info == 0)
```

that will result in

```
{a="1"} 0
```

hello_info(a="1",b="t2") 0

The aggregation operator `sum` is not relevant here as you are not interested in the result, you could also use `avg()` or any other.